# magento2: drop-down attribute call an image if its Yes

Tags: image, dropdown-attribute

i would like to call an image if the drop-down attribute is marked as "yes" from drop-down - if its "No" then i dont want to call an image. i am using the below code but this seems to pull the image for yes and no.

```
<div>

<?php //echo $_product->getAttributeText('discount'); 
if($_product->getAttributeText('discount')){ ?>
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/footer-logo.png'); ?>' alt="Demo">

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$_product->getAttributeText('discount')`; this will return either "Yes" or "No". Both will be validated to "true" by PHP, because they are strings with length > 0.

You can test this easily by doing:

```
<?php

var_dump((bool)"No"); // true
var_dump((bool)"Yes"); // also true
```

More info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.boolean.php Check the section "Converting to booleans".

The correct solution on your case would be:

```
<?php
if($_product->getDiscount()) { // either "1" or "0"
```